# How to unencode escaped XML with xQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I have a variable in xQuery of type xs:string with the value of an encoded HTML snippet (the content of a twitter tweet). It looks like this:

> Headlines-Today &#8226; AP sources:
>   &lt;b&gt;Obama&lt;/b&gt; pick for
>   Justice post withdraws : News - Rest
>   Of World - &lt;a
>   href=&quot;http://shar.es/mqMAG&quot;&gt;http://shar.es/mqMAG&lt;/a&gt;

When I try to write this out in an HTML block, I need the string to be unescaped so that the HTML snippet will be interpreted by the browser.  Instead the string is getting written out as is and the browser is rendering it as just text (so you see <a href="blah.... ). Here's how I'm writing out this string:

> {$entry/atom:content/text()}

How can I have the escaped characters unencoded so it writes < rather tha &lt; ?

I've tried to do a replacelike this but it always replaces the &lt; with &lt; !

> fn:replace($s, "&lt;", "<")

Answer (score 3):

In MarkLogic you can use the below query:

```
let $d := '<a>&lt;c&gt;asdf&lt;/c&gt;</a>' 

return xdmp:unquote ($d)
```

Answer (score 3):

in eXist, use util:parse():

```
util:parse(concat("<top>","&lt;c&gt;asdf&lt;/c&gt;",</top>")‌​)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As indeed it has :-( -  The eXist library util has a function parse which will parse a string provided it is well-formed XML. Uniless it is know that the string has a single root, it is best to add a top element:  util:parse(concat("<top>","&lt;c&gt;asdf&lt;/c&gt;",</top>"))

Comment: Better add your comment to the answer, edit and add what is needed

Comment: at least for eXist-db v4 or earlier this is true. In eXist-db 5 the function has been replaced by standard Query 3 functions, see below answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611480/how-to-unencode-escaped-xml-with-xquery/70844757#answer-70844757

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which **XQuery** processor you are using...  The easiest way is to be using a processor that has an extension that handles this for you.  For instance, with **Saxon** and the following **XML**:

```
<a>&lt;c&gt;asdf&lt;/c&gt;</a>
```

You can write an **XQuery** that uses the `saxon:parse()` function to do what you want:

```
declare namespace saxon = "http://saxon.sf.net/";

<a>{
  saxon:parse(doc('test.xml')/a)
}</a>
```

The result from that is:

```
<a>
  <c>asdf</c>
</a>
```

I think most(?) **XQuery** processors will have an extension to do this for you. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

since XQuery 3 you can use the `parse-xml()` or `parse-xml-fragment()` functions. See also:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-parse-xml
- https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-parse-xml-fragment