# Decoding escaped XML with Saxon HE

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon

I need to decode escaped XML using xquery, i.e. I have a string like `&amp;lt;` and I need to read it as `<`.

I'm using Saxon 9.6.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611480/how-to-unencode-escaped-xml-with-xquery) and tried to use `saxon:parse()`, but it didn't work (see below).

Is there a HE version of Saxon supporting `saxon:parse()` or `saxon:parse-xml()`?

Are there other alternatives to decode the escaped XML?

My query:

```
declare namespace saxon = "http://saxon.sf.net/";

saxon:parse("&lt;")
```

the result:

> Error on line 11 of query.xq:
>     XPST0017: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://saxon.sf.net/}parse().
>     Saxon extension functions are not available under Saxon-HE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are standard XPath 3.0 functions [`parse-xml()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml) and [`parse-xml-fragment()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml-fragment) which supersede `saxon:parse()`. They should work in Saxon-HE, but try 9.7 rather than 9.6.